# How to deal with Properties in Protocols and Getter and Setter of those properties in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following protocol:

```
@protocol CardTransferFundsDelegate <NSObject>
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<CardTransferFundsView> view;
@end
```

I have the following in the .h file:

```
@interface CardTopViewModel : NSObject<CardTransferFundsDelegate>
- (instancetype)initWithVirtualCard:(Card *)card;
@end
```

In my .m I have the following:

```
@interface CardTopUpViewModel()
@property (strong, nonatomic) Card *card;
@end

@implementation CardTopUpViewModel

-(instancetype)initWithCard:(Card *)card {
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.card = card;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id <CardTransferFundsView>)view {
    return nil;
}

- (void)setView:(id <CardTransferFundsView>)view {
    self.view = view;
}

@end
```

The issue I have is whenever I call `setView` it then calls `self.view` which then calls the getter method and I have a program that just keeps running infinitely.

So my question is, How do I fix this issue, such that the protocol still keeps the property but I am able to get and set the view without having the program run infinitely?

Comment: The code you posted does not call the getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implemented the setter, `setView`, in terms of itself, `set.view`, so it will recurse until the call stack overflows.

To implement the property specified in your protocol you need three things:

1. Storage - an instance variable in which to hold the properties value
2. A setter
3. A getter

First add an instance variable, say `myView`:

```
@implementation CardTopUpViewModel
{
   id <CardTransferFundsView>) myView; // storage for view property
}
```

Now your setter becomes:

```
- (void)setView:(id <CardTransferFundsView>)view
{
   myView = view;
}
```

And the getter is similarly trivial.

Or of course you can just skip all this and use a property declaration in your `@interface` which matches that in the protocol and the compiler will provide the storage, setter and getter automagically.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `self.view = view` will call the setter method again and again resulting infinite call. That moto is do not call setter method in with in setter method (setting property will call it again). So Issue in below lines. so view is already a property of viewcontroller. `- (void) setView:(id)view` is setter method for the view Property. try use another name.

Basically you should be very careful while creating method start with set. Usually try to use method name which starts with any **verb** as it does some action.

```
- (void)setView:(id <CardTransferFundsView>)view {
    self.view = view;
}
```

create any property of `id <CardTransferFundsView>)` with other name and use with in setter method in place of `self.view = view`.